# How to get un-overwritten functions from Base to update to overwritten function in derived?

Tags: c++

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I wasn't able to find it elsewhere.

```
class Base {
  public:
    template <typename T>
    T A(T param, T param2) {
      return param + param2;
    }
    int B() {
        return A(1, 1);
    }
};
class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    template <typename T>
    T A(T param, T param2) {
      return param * param2;
    }
};
int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.B(); // We'd like to see this be 1 since we overwrote A. As is, it
           // is 2.
    return 0;
}
```

If we have a derived class like above and want to modify one of the functions such that all other functions that call it (inherited from base class), is there a way to do this without having to copy over each of the functions (if there's a lot of B-like functions that call A, I don't want to have to copy paste a bunch of them into derived class).

Comment: "Overwritten" is not a word that is being used by the C++ language to describe functions. There are overridden functions, and there are overloaded functions. It is recommended to learn what each one means. `A` is neither. `Base::A` and `Derived::A` are simply unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the function `A` in the base a `virtual` function so that runtime polymorphism take place.

```
class Base 
{
  public:    
    virtual int A(int param, int param2) // virtual A
    {
      return param + param2;
    }
    // ....
    // ~Base () = default;
};
class Derived : public Base 
{
  public:    
    int A(int param, int param2) override  // override  the base A
    {
      return param * param2;
    }
};
```

Now the

```
Derived d;
std::cout << d.B();  // --> prints 1
```

See demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EjbrMaKW3

Comment: Ok this does work, though I guess my example is not good enough.

What happens if function A is a templated function?
I'm seeing: 'virtual' cannot be specified on member function templates

Comment: @dcheng Yes, that is correct. If it is a templated classes, you may want to look into the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern); aka **static polymorphism**!

Comment: Class itself doesn't have to be templated. Just the function.
Ie. if in Base:
```
template typename<T>
T A(T param, T param2) {
      return param + param2;
}
```

I'll go update the main post.

Comment: @dcheng Then I do not see any other ways except defining own `B` function : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7KE9qfM9h

Comment: Ok, I'll mark this as the answer for now, unless someone actually has a way to do this without copying B over. Thanks!